# Securing API Keys in Javascript

Tags: javascript, security, cakephp, api-key

I'm building a payment plugin for a website, where users can buy some website intern currency with real money. the backend i use, which handles the payment process, is [this](http://www.payone.de/).
It provides (beside others) a JavaScript library to communicate with their API, so you don't have to let your system touch sensitive payment data like credit card numbers etc.

The problem is:
For now the api-key, secret hash and other vulnerable data are hardcoded just into my script which initiates the communication with the server. so in theory every half-descent user could just copy them out of the browser and could do nasty sh*t with it, especially if they have access to the api documentation.

So, this isn't secure and it definitely cannot go live this way.

im working with cakephp and i thought of collecting those sensitive keys with some ajax calls to my controllers/models, after pressing on the submit button.
There's the problem, that this connection isn't secured and can easily be 'man-in-the-middled'.

Are there other, better ways to secure my API Keys in javascript?

Comment: Nope. Any sensitive information needs to go through *your* servers. But if they have a JS interface, surely *they* have thought about security?

Comment: Also, not in any way related to cake..?

Answer (score -1):

Use token based auth, https and csrf tokens and never, ever, but a secret on the client.

Use oauth so users don't even need to send you a password. Use someone else's authentication system.